# ROS navigation without amcl / localization?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to run ROS navigation without amcl or any kind of localization? I still want to a static map that I built using gmapping, just don't want any localization.

Would that mean I should publish a zero transform from /map to /odom? My tree earlier was map -> odom -> base_link and amcl used to publish the transform from map to odom.
EDIT: I did the above but I am unable to set the initial pose of the robot in the map using rviz.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190281/ros-navigation-without-amcl-/-localization-?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was quite simple. You cannot set the initialpose using rviz since odom and map are the same now. So I reflected the initialpose into the static transform that I am publishing from map to odom.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0